# Why is TrimRight searching from the beginning of the string?

Tags: c++, mfc

This nearly tripped me, when I double checked some code, and I am wondering what I'm missing.

Here's how [`TrimRight`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fy06s064.aspx) is implemented (this is from VS2005 MFC):

```
// Remove all trailing occurrences of character 'chTarget'
CStringT& TrimRight( __in XCHAR chTarget )
{
    // find beginning of trailing matches
    // by starting at beginning (DBCS aware)

    PCXSTR psz = GetString();
    PCXSTR pszLast = NULL;

    while( *psz != 0 )
    {
        if( *psz == chTarget )
        {
            if( pszLast == NULL )
            {
                pszLast = psz;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            pszLast = NULL; // Note: any other char resets search pos
        }
        psz = StringTraits::CharNext( psz );
    }

    if( pszLast != NULL )
    {
        // truncate at left-most matching character  
        ....
```

This implementation seems just plain weird. Wouldn't it be much more natural (and faster) to search from the end of the string?

Comment: Have you considered the "DBCS aware" part of the comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @Angew's comment is spot on:

> `starting at beginning (DBCS aware)`
>
> `psz = StringTraits::CharNext( psz );`

This function has to work correctly with multi-byte character sets and so it has to scan forwards to correctly identify multi width characters.